# Hiding a CSS Dropdown Menu in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a CSS menu with an HTML structure like:

```
<div class="toolmenu" style="min-width:800px">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="dropdown left" href="#">Main A</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="dropdown right" href="#">Main B<span class="tm-arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="tm-width-2">
                <li><a href="#">Sub i</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub ii</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub iii</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub iv</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

The CSS can be seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/nfvqL/3/).

It works great, except that the sub-menu does not close once an item is clicked.  Since the menu items trigger an Ajax update to the page, it makes for a quirky UI experience.

To solve that problem, I tried a little JavaScript:

```
$('div.toolmenu ul li ul li a').click(function () {
    var grand = $(this).parent().parent();
    grand.css('display', 'none');
    setInterval(function () {
        grand.css('display', '');
    }, 300);
});
```

That works wonderfully in *most* browsers.  IE, however, behaves as follows:

- Submenu disappears on click
- Submenu reappears after setInterval's callback fires

How can I make this work in IE as well?  Is there a better approach to causing the submenu to disappear after it is clicked?

Comment: IE9 on Win7 seems to be behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making it reappear with the interval, you can make it appear on mouse enter function. Try this:

```
$('div.toolmenu ul li ul li a').click(function () {
    var grand = $(this).parent().parent();
    grand.hide();

});

$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).next('ul').show();
});
```

If you want to create a more animated menu you can replace hide with fadeOut() and show with fadeIn().

EDIT: This is your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfvqL/4/) modified.